# Differentiate $x^{a^x}$ without logarithmic differentiation?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, logarithms, exponential-function, chain-rule

Problem. Compute $\frac{d}{dx} x^{a^x}$.

**Method 1: Logarithmic Differentiation (Correct):**

\begin{align*}
y&= x^{a^x} \\
\ln(y)&=a^x \cdot \ln(x) \\
\frac{1}{y} \frac{dy}{dx} &=a^x \frac{1}{x} + \ln(x) \ln(a) a^x \\
\frac{dy}{dx} &= y\left(\frac{1}{x} a^x + \ln(a) \ln(x) a^x\right) \\
\frac{dy}{dx} &= x^{a^x}\left(\frac{1}{x} a^x + \ln(a) \ln(x) a^x\right) \\
\frac{dy}{dx} &= a^x x^{a^x}\left(\frac{1}{x} + \ln(a) \ln(x)\right) \\
\frac{dy}{dx} &= a^x x^{a^x-1}\left(1 + x\ln(a) \ln(x) \right) \\
\end{align*}

**Method 2: Chain Rule (Incorrect):**

\begin{align*}
y&= x^{a^x} \\
\frac{dy}{dx} &= a^x x^{a^x-1} \cdot \left[\ln(a) \cdot a^x\right]
\end{align*}

Method 2 is incorrect because it $x^{a^x}$ is not a power function, so we cannot apply power rule (thanks @Alann_Rosas and @Parcly_Taxel).

**My Question:** Can [Ninad Munshi's answer here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3900016/100167) be adopted to correct **method 2** without the use of logarithmic differentiation? What is the name (and/or proof) of this generalized version of chain rule?

Thank you!

Comment: $x^{a^x}$ is not a power function.

Comment: Got it, thank you! Is there any way to correct method 2 or solve the problem without logarithmic differentiation?

Comment: I don't think so. The most natural way to define the expression $f(x)^{g(x)}$ is to write $f(x)^{g(x)}:=\exp\left[g(x)\ln f(x)\right]$, so logarithmic differentiation seems inevitable.

Comment: Please do not modify your question after you have received an answer.

Comment: I think you can proceed as in @AlannRosas comment by writing your function as $\exp(a^x\log x) $.

Comment: Also I don't see how the chain rule can be applied here unless we use $\exp, \log$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested, one can use the answer in [Why the chain rule does not work for this question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3900006/why-the-chain-rule-does-not-work-for-this-question/3900016#3900016) to solve this problem.

\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dx} x^{a^x} 
&= a^x \cdot x^{a^x-1} + x^{a^x} \cdot \ln(x) \cdot \frac{d}{dx} a^x \\
&= a^x \cdot x^{a^x-1} + x^{a^x} \cdot \ln(x) \cdot \ln(a) \cdot a^x
\end{align*}

This is a special case of the [multivariable chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule#Case_of_f(g1(x),_..._,_gk(x))).

Comment: Thank you! Do you know the name of this "generalized" version of chain rule? Or could you point me in the direction of where I could find a proof of this generalized form of chain rule?

Comment: Look in  the index of your calculus book for this: "Chain rule for partial derivatives"

Answer (score 3):

It is not a misapplication of the chain rule, but of the power rule. The power rule does not work for non-constant exponents; by that logic the derivative of $x^x$ would be $x\cdot x^{x-1}=x^x$, which is flat-out wrong.

Comment: Got it, thank you! Is there any way to correct method 2, or solve the problem without logarithmic differentiation?

Comment: @Mathemanic Please ask that in another question.

Comment: Edited original post to clarify question and intent.